# INSTALL_REFERRER not received on production

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-broadcast, google-analytics-firebase

I'm not getting install referrer received on application installed from the play store. Below is my Androidmanifest.xml shows receiver which is inside `<application>` tag too.

```
  <receiver
        android:name="com.usplnew.getreferrer.CustomReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And below is code for Receiver

```
public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("sgn RECEIVED");
        Log.d("YES", "IT WORKS!!");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Received Intall Referrer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Its working well with below command on emulator and device too

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.uspl.getrefferer/com.uspl.getrefferer.CustomReceiver --es "referrer" "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.NextGen.Water.Run&referrer=IWantThisReferrer"
```

I also put the same below code into the app into the production on Google Play. But INSTALL REFERRER is not received when the application is installed.

I would highly appreciate if someone guide where I'm wrong.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @PDsHAH5382 ... Did u get the solution of these problem??

Comment: @DavidLiu .. Did u get the solution of these problem

Comment: Did you find the solution? as I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your implementation of your own class of BroadcastReceiver with this documentation - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v1/devguide#campaigns
?