# How to create the Url which contains DATA like Custom url or Deep linking?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I tried the below link but getting the proper way of how to do this.

[1st link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193683/android-deep-linking-issue-how-to-use-custom-url-scheme-myapp-some-data),
[2nd link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023273/android-custom-url-scheme),
[3rd link](http://androblip.huiges.nl/2010/05/19/opening-urls-with-your-application/),
[4th link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228#3472228),
[5th link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042278/launch-android-application-from-a-browser-link/13044911#13044911)

By these above links i only get to know that how can we get the data from the custom link.

Here is my code.

```
   //get uri data
     Uri data = getIntent().getData();
     //get schma
     String scheme = data.getScheme(); // "http"
     //get server name
     String host = data.getHost(); // Ipaddress or domain name
    //get parameter
     String urltextboxname=data.getQueryParameter("name");
     //set value in textview
     name.setText(urltextboxname);
```

**BUT**
My problem is that i want to create the custom link or deep linking on button click like I want to pass my UNIQUE ID in the link. and send it to other user by **SMS** or by **EMAIL**. And , when the user click on the link from **SMS** or **EMAIL** then user should navigate to the GOOGLE PLAY store , and install the application with my data on it. like the referral program application. Please help me to short out from these problem , pardon me if there any grammatical mistake on it.

Comment: You want a link that would lead the user to the Play store, for him to choose to install your app, or a link that would install the app from Play store directly?

Comment: Yes that what i exactly looking for.

Comment: Having the link directly installing the app from Play store?

Comment: @StanCt ... Yes , by link there should we install the application.Now we are using these concept... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31047924/install-referrer-not-received-on-production .............. But did not get the INSTALL_REFERRER in my  application .... Please help to short out from thes problem .

Comment: So I imagine that you have created your own BroadcastReceiver cast for your custom referrer links, am I correct? Have you correctly created those referrer links? Please check this information and see if its any help - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v1/devguide#google-play-tracking

Comment: @StanCt ... As we are using the BroadCast receiver to receive the INSTALL_REFFERENCE.... But the problem is that we getting the install reference in our receiver and getting NULL...please help me to short out from these problem